# LNK1561 Linking Error in MSVS2010 when main is defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, entry-point

I have been making several projects to compile small SDL code tutorials from a tutorial site in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 using C++>Empty Projects; and all of these projects have compiled fine. In all of these projects I've used this version of main for my entry point:

```
int main (int argc, char* args[]) {
    //code...
    return 0;
}
```

I am new to SDL and C++, but from what I understand this your basic entry point for ALL SDL applications. However, I continuously receive a LNK1561 linking error (means the linker couldn't find an entry point) on my new projects. I've tried making new projects and redefining all my SDL dependencies (sorry if thats wrong terminology) in the project editor like I did with the project that worked, and I still get a linking error. Is there some project property I need to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay nevermind, I knew it would be something stupid I overlooked... I set the subsystem wrong in the Linker options of my project properties.